# BitConverter toInt32

Tags: c#

В чем проблема?

> EXCEPTION OCCURED AT 09.10.2017 6:13:11 FROM PROCESS MESSAGES (TYPE: Data DATATYPE: BasicSync)
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции.
>   Имя параметра: startIndex
>      в System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
>      в System.BitConverter.ToInt32(Byte[] value, Int32 startIndex)

Значения которые приходят:

```
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC - System.Byte[] | 16 (Велечина массива, Ниже все значения которые хранятся в массиве)
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 6
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 0
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 0
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 0
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 43
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 155
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 135
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 195
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 226
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 87
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 34
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 196
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 211
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 79
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 4
[06:41:33] BASICSYNC FOR - 66
```

Сам код:

```
BitConverter.ToInt32(data, len) //(len - 16)
```

Comment: data как у вас объявлено и инициализировано?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Велечина" массива - `16`, и `len` в `BitConverter.ToInt32(data, len)` - тоже `16`?

Вылезаете за границу массива `data`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx

> Второй параметр должен быть больше или равен нулю и меньше длины
>   массива минус три.

Comment: То есть len+1??

Comment: @Alexander не понял вопроса

Comment: Типо, data = 16
len тогда должен быть равен чему?

Comment: @Alexander типо, любое число от нуля до тринадцати